# Stream online json information asynchronously

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to make a program that uses data to find solutions to large 3D mathematical nets. In JSON format, there is an array of nodes and information about their position in 3D space and what properties do they have etc. You can request two kinds of formatting:

Standard JSON array: `https://www.example.com/nodes.json`

```
[{"ID": 1, "Type": "Node", "x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0}, {"ID": 2, "Type": "OtherNode", "x": 1, "y": 0, "z": 0}, ...
```

Line delimited array: `https://www.example.com/nodes.jsonl`

```
{"ID": 1, "Type": "Node", "x": 0, "y": 0, "z": 0}
{"ID": 2, "Type": "OtherNode", "x": 1, "y": 0, "z": 0}
...
```

My class:

```
class Node
{
    ulong ID { get; set; }
    nodeType Type { get; set; }
    decimal X { get; set; }
    decimal Y { get; set; }
    decimal Z { get; set; }
}
```

These node collections can get very large. Possibly GBs large but thankfully only needs to update once every day. The issue is if I have it download the JSON async the program still won't be useable until the entire thing is downloaded.

```
WebClient.DownloadFile(settings.URL, path);
List<Node> nodes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Node>>(path);
```

However, if I have the first few nodes I can still start to solve the net without having the entire set of nodes. If I could download the file one character at a time using a stream of some kind I can get around it. Using the line delimited format I can something like this:

```
SomeStream someStream = new SomeStream(URL);
while(!someStream.eof)
{
    string jsonString = someStream.ReadLine();
    nodes.Add(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Node>(jsonString));
}
```

I fear that this might not be possible unless the website supports requesting data one line at a time. If something else fixes the issue I will still be more than open to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *json parser* I know that has an `IAsyncEnumerbale` deseralizer (yet)

However, we should be able to do this with a regular iterator as long as you don't dispose the stream

```
public static IEnumerable<Node> ReadStream(Stream stream)
{
   var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

   using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
   using var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader) {SupportMultipleContent = true};

   while (jsonReader.Read())
      yield return serializer.Deserialize<Node>(jsonReader);
}
```

**Example**

```
var httpclient = new HttpClient(); // dont do this, just an example

// note don't dispose the stream until its finished enumerating, or your will regret it
var stream = await httpclient.GetStreamAsync("https://www.example.com/nodes.json");
foreach (var item in ReadStream(stream))
   Console.WriteLine(item.ID);
```

<sub>***Note** : This is completely untested as i don't have a url that will give me continuous feed of json without mucking around and writing one*</sub>

Comment: Had to add ?'s to non-nullable types to allow null in the JSONs besides that this worked perfectly.